# Blockchain check gap api returns empty json

Tags: blockchain

I'm requesting to: https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/checkgap

But the endpoint returns empty json.

```
{}
```

This is so sudden and is ruining my app. May I know the possible reason why this happened?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @DrJay have you gotten any solution?

Comment: nope i think they change their stricture of things